# Migrate not successful, DB is broken. How to fix, or at least output static HTML without plugins?

Tags: database, migration, permissions

Sup guys.

So, I developed this website, and for the 3rd time it crashed when I tried to migrate (I used several techniques, all of them worked at some point with, but not with this website). The pages/post lists are empty, although the system actually displays the number of pages I created before. When I try to edit any page or post, or even access a plugin dashboard, it says I don't have permission to do that. I might edit pages using Visual Composer preview mode, but sometimes it doesn't save the changes, and I'm not able to create any new page.

So, now, I'm trying to output the current website to HTML, so I can work on the definitive path with a new Wordpress, without my customer actually realizing (since the website is published, but on HTML) I'm doing it, but I can't use any plugin, and HTTrack seems to never get the job done... has anyone ever faced anything similar?

If someone wanna help debug it, please access http://www.casadosoculostatuape.com.br...

Answer (score 0):

What have you done exactly upon migration?
What install did you try to migrate from? Local, another domain?

My little checklist for migration:

- use [MigrateDB plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/) to export a database. Use it to replace the old domain with the new one in the database
- use [BackUpWordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/backupwordpress/) to do a Complete backup of the development site (with database also just in case)
- upload files to new host
- create a database for that website and upload the database generated by MigrateDB.
- edit the wp-config.php to match the new server's configuration and database info.
- test it out. In most cases it just works

Some things you should maybe check :

- do the versions from you dev site and production site match each other: wordpress, PHP, Mysql?
- what is the charset of your db in each install? Sometimes it could be different and mess with a lot of things

So i could help you further more it'd be great if you could activate set WP_DEBUG to "true" in the wp-config.php and check for php errors.
Maybe also install Php [Error log monitor plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/error-log-monitor/) to see if it returns valuable information.

Finally and generally speaking, a good process to have to avoid such problems : before uploading to live site, create a subdomain on the same server (dev.casadosoculostatuape.com.br in your case) and try to migrate on this one... this way you won't have to deal with those problems AFTER the site is supposed to be online ;)

edit:

i know i don't directly answer the problem but my advice would be to directly debug the install without loosing more time.

Another question for you: can you provide a list of the plugins you dev site used?

If you answer my message with all the info i'll probably could help.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for answering! I'm pretty desperate here...

I actually just moved one folder above. The problem is: I used Wordpress system itself to do the change of the URLs, without any plugins. That probably broke the website (although the bugs are still pretty specific). I'm used to do like this, then just transfer the files to the new location. When I move from one host to another, I usually do all by myself... export the SQL, backup the files, import the SQL (after the needed changes, usually related to SQL commands), and put the files in the new location. +

Comment: + This has always done the job pretty well.  I'll from now on, however, used these plugins u've mentioned.

To all of these questions, the answer would be "is everything compatible", for I actually only moved folders on the same domain, and didn't have to export/import the DB.

I did that WP-DEBUG, but it didn't display anything really relevant.
I also turned on the PHP debug, and nothing appeared. I'll attach the screenshots.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5bSRw

Comment: do you have access to your pages when changing for a default wordpress theme and deactivating all plugins ?

Comment: As far as i can see for me your problem is not with the migration but with some plugin.
Try deactivating them all and switch for a default theme. Does it work or does the bug persists? If it works then reactivate one by one your plugins and this way you can identify where the problem comes from

Comment: Already tried both of them, changing the theme and deactivating the plugins. The problems remained the same.

Comment: i can't advice you anything more with the info at hand than doing a proper migration, the good way, not by hand.

Answer (score 0):

I recently migrated five WordPress sites to a new host using the Duplicator Pro plugin. I installed the plugin in each site and set up the storage location to be offline in DropBox so the backup files wouldn't take up so much room on the site. You do need to follow their directions exactly.

Before running it (making a package) be sure to clear all website and browser cache and history. Also, before running it, deactivate all security plugins such as Wordfence because it interferes with installing the database. After you've migrated the site, you can turn security plugins back on.